# c# Binding windows forms controls in designer without typing any code

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, c#-4.0, windows-forms-designer

I need to bind two controls (pictureboxes) in my c# windowsforms designer (using Visual Studio 2015) so when I do an action with the parent one (for example hide it), the child will also hide... but on the other hand, when i hide the child, the parent will stay the way it is...is there a way to do this just in the designer without typing any code?
I couldn't find any answer on the Internet.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean the behaviour to happen at runtime or at design time or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way of doing this in the designer. You will have to implement this behavior using some code.